# How can i upgrade and load a module in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am getting the error in Powershell as follows:

```
 Get-AzWebApp : The 'Get-AzWebApp' command was found in the module 'Az.Websites', but the 
 module could not be loaded.
```

Which module do i need to Load here ?

Also my Az module is version 10.0.0 , I want to upgrade to 10.3.0 . I have tried

```
 Install-Module -Name Az -RequiredVersion 10.3.0
```

Then i ran Get-InstalledModule Az  , but still gave version 10.0.0 . Any ideas on how to upgrade ?

Comment: Try adding -force -allowclobber

Comment: so i add Install-Module -Name Az -RequiredVersion 10.3.0  -force -allowclobber  ?

Comment: Yes that's what I would try.  Keep in mind multiple versions can be installed.  The -scope flag allows you to define who (and therefore the path) you are installing the module for.  You could have 1 version installed for yourself and another version installed for all users.